# Sorting two different parts of the same array C

Tags: c, arrays, qsort

I've been playing around a bit and I've done a program that plays the lottery (EuroMillions), and I was able to do it.

I got four arrays, two for the numbers and two for the stars, and then I'd sort both so I could more easily compare them.

So here's my question, can I sort only the first five numbers and then the last two, separately? Or do I really need to have four arrays like I did?

What I used to sort:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

and

```
qsort(b, 7, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
```

If the code is needed I can post it, but it's rather big.

Comment: What five numbers? What does that mean?

Comment: Add 100 to the stars so they get sorted above the non-stars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `b` is an int array with 7 elements you can do this

```
qsort(b, 5, sizeof(int), cmpfunc); // sort 5 elements starting from b 
qsort(b + 5, 2, sizeof(int), cmpfunc); // sort 2 elements starting from b+5
```

In each case the first 2 arguments are the pointer to the start of a memory block and the number of elements.

So if `b` is defined as

```
int b[] = {8, 2, 12, 4, 5, 7, 6};
```

you will get

```
{2, 4, 5, 8, 12, 6,7}
```

Comment: This answer looks correct assuming qsort is the one defined in stdlib

Comment: I tried using b[5] instead of b+5. Thank you for the help!

Comment: This is so trivial, compared to actually figuring out qsort itself, I'm surprised OP was actually asking for this answer.

Comment: @this It's probably fairly easy to skip understanding how pointers actually work and start looking for code samples of qsort that can be minimally-adapted.

Comment: @Ike Unfortunately. But samples found online must be correct because they are online and their author claims they are correct. /s